# Добавление существующего виджета в другой Qt Python

Tags: qt, pyqt5

1. Как имея объект без предка добавить его в существующий виджет. Например:

```
 btn = QPushButton()
 q = QWidget()
```

Необходимо добавить btn в q не на этапе создания QPushButton(q), а после, не используя макеты.

Comment: Ваша идея не совсем понятная. Если вы разместите свой пример и поясните, что вы хотите сделать, вы получите больше полезной информации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Два варианта:

1) Прямо указать родителя можно с помощью [setParent](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QWidget.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget.setParent)
И, потом, указать координаты кнопки непосредственно.

2) Использовать компоновщики ([QLayout](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_qboxlayout_class.htm) и производные от него классы). Это обеспечит автоматическое позиционирование кнопок.

```
vbox = QVBoxLayout()
vbox.addWidget(btn)
q.setLayout(vbox)
```